# How should I design my Scala CRUD?

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I was looking for articles about `Scala` design patterns but I found it hard to find. The one that I found, `Cake Pattern`, seems that you must need a bunch of code to do simple things.
So, what I'm doing? A `Java` code in `Scala` :(
I would love to find some examples here or in a blog about how to mix trait in a good way to provide a good design to my systems.

Sample:

```scala
trait DAO {
  def create: Model
}
trait MongoDAO extends DAO {
  override def create: Model = ???
}
class MyBussiness(dao: DAO) {
  def validateAndStore(m: Model) = {
    dao.create(m)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to design patterns as understood by OOP, many of them stop making sense. Functions: composition, higher order, application... - lets you get away without creating things named `Factory`, `Builder`, and so on. ([Here](https://www.slideshare.net/ScottWlaschin/fp-patterns-buildstufflt) you have Some nice presentation about the subject. In F#, but it applies to all FP.)

Instead, try to embrace the functional aspect of Scala. Great starting point is [Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala). As you start to internalize FP concepts, you will feel less and less need for using any sort of patterns, as you could express most of your ideas with just a thought-through composition of functions.

When you start feeling comfortable with Scala's syntax and all it's functional concepts, start reading about Cats, Scalaz and Shapeless - those 3 libraries provides you some more advanced FP concepts. Later on you might also start looking for a FP papers. [Here](https://gist.github.com/jdegoes/97459c0045f373f4eaf126998d8f65dc) you have some summary of some more advanced things you can eventually do with Scala and FP.

As for a cake pattern in a long run, most of the people I know (me including) arrives at conclusion that this is a anti-pattern. Even Play gave up on this approach.

In your CRUD aim for simplicity. Make use of functional composition and immutability. You won't get everything right on your first, try - learning OOP took you time, FP isn't different in that regard.

Comment: I didn't hope to receive a soo good answer like this. Thak you!